# OS X 10.9: 'ImportError: No module named glibc'

Tags: macos, python

I needed to do a clean reinstall with Maverick and am now trying to get everything python related set up and running again. Now I have trouble using pip and I keep getting `ImportError: No module named glibc`whenever I try to do anything with pip. I don't really know what to do now. I found glibc versions to download, but do I need those? How would I install glibc?
Cheers, guys!

Comment: Which version of python is this?

Comment: It's 2.7. I think my problem is, that I am new to programming and having to set up my os again f*d up all my libraries and dependencies. I just now got pip to run by installing command line tools, but now I can't get selenium to work, though it is in my vitualenv venv folder. Is there **any resource (on or offline) where I can learn about where and how to set up all these packages and libraries and what not?** all necessary information is spread across 100 websites. although I've been using pip and homebrew I can't get things to work and I guess it's down to canopy not knowing where to look.

Comment: Ah homebrew - that is info you need to provide as it changes things. what is the path of the pip you are running - basically the rule is use one packaging manage only - pip and homebrew are different and you need to take care. Why do you need homebrew?

Comment: I was using homebrew because some page where I was looking for downloads told me so... I'm new, you know ;)  I switched to canopy package manager and selenium is working now, too. I will close this question, but do you have any advice for me, where to look for info about all these aspects of programming (libraries, setting up my environment, $PATH etc.) I learned nothing about this in my programming course and I guess pip and home-brew were the reason I had to reinstall my os in the first place...